# I want to make this script realtime by jQuery, How do I do that?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am currently learning Javascript and I am at the most basic level someone could be.

I wrote a simple script for generating a referral link for envato market.

Its a very simple function which gets the profile url and username and a onclick is used to combine these variables and put the ?ref= in there.

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
 <head>
  <title>JS</title>
 </head>
 <body>
  <script>
   function  refferalGen() {
    var userName = document.getElementById("username").value;
    var profUrl = document.getElementById("profurl").value;
    var result = (profUrl) + "?ref=" + (userName);

    document.getElementById("resulttxt").value = result;
   }
  </script>

  <input style="width:250px" type="text" id="username" placeholder="Username" /><br>
  <input style="width:250px" type="text" id="profurl" placeholder="Profile Url" /><br>
  <input style="width:250px" type="text" id="resulttxt" placeholder="Result Will be printed here" /><br>
  <input style="width:250px" type="button" name="clickbait" onclick="refferalGen()" value="Clickbait !" />

 </body>
</html>
```

I want it to be so that I dont have to use the button to get the result Instead it is real-time.

When i type in the username textfield it automatically updates the result field instantly and same goes for the profile url field.

Thanks to anyone who replies.

Comment: I have a question before i post an answer. are you posting or sending any data to server in any form which is being captured from these inputs?

Comment: [The HTML5 placeholder attribute is not a substitute for the label element](http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/201204/the_html5_placeholder_attribute_is_not_a_substitute_for_the_label_element/)

Comment: Don't use an input element for showing [output](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/output).

Answer (score 3):

Use an [`input`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/input), [`keypress`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/keypress) or [`change`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/change) event on the input instead of a click event on the button.

Comment: I have been `jQuerying` for more than 4 years now, and yet I didn't know that the `input` event existed, the more you know :)

Answer (score 1):

Use `onkeypress` event on any input you want to call function as user presses keys like this:

```
onkeypress="refferalGen()"
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
 <head>
  <title>JS</title>
 </head>
 <body>
  <script>
   function  refferalGen() {
    var userName = document.getElementById("username").value;
    var profUrl = document.getElementById("profurl").value;
    var result = (profUrl) + "?ref=" + (userName);

    document.getElementById("resulttxt").value = result;
   }
  </script>

  <input style="width:250px" type="text" id="username" onkeypress="refferalGen()" placeholder="Username" /><br>
  <input style="width:250px" type="text" id="profurl" placeholder="Profile Url" onkeypress="refferalGen()" /><br>
  <input style="width:250px" type="text" id="resulttxt" placeholder="Result Will be printed here" /><br>
  <input style="width:250px" type="button" name="clickbait" onclick="refferalGen()" value="Clickbait !" />

 </body>
</html>
```

instead of `keypress` event you can also use `oninput`, input event works just like `onchange` but change event only triggers when element lost focus.

Comment: Thanks for this solution. Greatly Appreciated

Comment: @Demoncious,you're wlecome,If someone's answer solved your problem, you might want to accept it as the answer using the big checkbox.